# Rails - Legacy database integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails app with both a native rails database and a legacy database.

I query these legacy tables just fine,  BUT I have to insert records into them as well.

But the Legacy table does not conform to rails convention WRT the key.  Instead of an auto incrementing integer, the Legacy Key is a string (always numeric characters 0-9, but still a string attribute in the DB).  The Legacy database has a table where the current index value is stored,  and an insert operation requires reading from the 'current_index' table the current index value,  incrementing it by 1,  and saving the value back to 'index_table',  then returning the new value,  which is used in the insert statement for the new key value.

Right now I have the hand crafted SQL required to insert records scattered in various controllers. I'd like to clean that up,  and move it into the model.

Currently I do this:

legacy_table.db:

```
class LegacyTable < Ldb
  self.table_name = "legacyTableName"
  self.primary_key "legacyKeyName"
end
```

in controller:

```
def insert_legacy_record(attrs)
  result = Ldb.connection.exec_query("
      DECLARE @key int;
      EXEC dbo.getKeyField @key OUTPUT, 'RecordKey';
      SELECT @key as ref_key;
    ")
    newkey = result.first['ref_key']

  result = Ldb.connection.exec_query("
    INSERT INTO legacyTableName 
    (legacyKeyName,foo,...) 
    VALUES 
    ('#{newkey}','#{attrs[:foo]}',...)
  ")
end
```

This is a pain,  as I have to manually maintain the list of table attributes and their corresponding values input as attrs.

Can I just override the index generation part of activeRecord?  Such that I could do this:

OPTION1

```
@item = LegacyTable.new
@item.attributes(data)
@item.save  <=== somehow override new index value generation
```

Or should I just override the new method, and have it return the new key value it generates?

OPTION2

```
newkey = LegacyTable.new(data)
@new = LegacyTable.find(newkey)
```

I know how to do OPTION2, is OPTION1 possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an initializer:

```
module Extensions
  module LegacyModelId
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      before_create :generate_legacy_id

      def generate_legacy_id
        result = Ldb.connection.exec_query("
          DECLARE @key int;
          EXEC dbo.getKeyField @key OUTPUT, 'RecordKey';
          SELECT @key as ref_key;
        ")

        self.id = result.first['ref_key']
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In each of your legacy models:

```
class LegacyModelFoo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Extensions::LegacyModelId

  ...
end
```

This will add the `before_create` callback on each model you include the extension in, causing it to do the lookup and assign the new id.

Comment: Both answers answered the fundamental question, which is 'just set id prior to the save'.  This solution is very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

How about overriding `create` method in your `LegacyTable` model like this:

```
 def create
   # new_id = The code you use to get/set a new id for insertion
   self.id = new_id
   super # continue as normal
 end
```